# How to display Exception (type) pass into AddModelError?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, addmodelerror

ValidationSummary only display it if I pass in `exception.Message`.

it display nothing if I pass in `exception`.

But `AddModelError` accept Exception type.

How do I display `Exception`?

cshtml:

```
@model ControlTower2.Models.ViewModelUploadRawMaterial

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UploadRawMaterialSupplierData";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>UploadRawMaterialSupplierData</h2>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadRawMaterialSupplierData", "PurchaseOrder", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.uploadFile, "", new { type = "file" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.uploadFile, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadRawMaterialSupplierData(ViewModelUploadRawMaterial viewModelUploadRawMaterial)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("test UploadRawMaterialSupplierData error!");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", exception);
        return View(viewModelUploadRawMaterial);
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class ViewModelUploadRawMaterial
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.UploadPurchaseOrder), ErrorMessageResourceName = "errorUploadFileRequired")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile { get; set; }

    public List<UploadExcelError> UploadExcelErrors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `ValidationSummary()` only uses the `ErrorMessage` property of each `ModelError`, it does not read the `Exception` property. You can view the [source code here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ValidationExtensions.cs) - (I'm not sure what the point of that overload is since it does not appear to be used anywhere)

Answer (score 0):

`ModelState.AddModelError()` accepts a `string` value. It is primarily used to display a *friendly* error on-screen for the user to see something went wrong.

You could analyse the exception and add an additional 'internal code' of your own devising that the user could quote to you to help you investigate any issues maybe?

e.g. *Sorry there was a problem completing your action [ERR:1234]* (where `1234` is your internal reference for something).

Alternatively, if you want to output the whole Exception regardless of UX, you could install `Newtonsoft JSON.NET` package via Nuget and serialize the Exception to a string passing that through like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadRawMaterialSupplierData(ViewModelUploadRawMaterial viewModelUploadRawMaterial)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("test UploadRawMaterialSupplierData error!");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        string jsonException = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exception);
        ModelState.AddModelError("", jsonException);
        return View(viewModelUploadRawMaterial);
    }
}
```